# Get title of current section of a specific level (similar to \thesection)

Tags: macros, sectioning, cross-referencing

Similar to `thesection`, `thesubsection`, ... I want to obtain the title of a section (as it is in the body of the document), via for example (pseudo-code) `\thesectiontitle`, `\thesubsectiontitle`, ...
The solution should not use the TOC as I want to be able to use custom titles for the TOC (via `\section[custom title]{body title}`).

Answer (score 2):

Since the logical structure of a document follows a hierarchy, and you would only be interested in the title of a higher element in the hierarchy, the following elementary patch to `\@sect` works:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@startsection}{\gdef\thesectiontype{#1}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\@sect}{\@namedef{the\thesectiontype title}{#8}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\@ssect}{\@namedef{the\thesectiontype title}{#5}}{}{}
\makeatother

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example
\begin{document}

\section{A section}

\subsection{A subsection}
\thesectiontitle

\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\thesectiontitle \par
\thesubsectiontitle

\subsection*{Another subsection}
\thesectiontitle

\subsubsection{Another subsubsection}
\thesectiontitle \par
\thesubsectiontitle

\end{document}
```

You can define some defaults to that `\thesectiontitle` returns nothing if called when there has been no `\section` called (say). However, I'm not sure how necessary this is given the current description.

Comment: There is also `\@ssect`, though.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti: Yes, I'll add that. It requires a little more work to capture the sectional type.

Comment: Unfortunately, the sectional type (_e.g._, `subsection`) is not an argument of `\@ssect`; but do you actually need it?

Answer (score 1):

Due to lack of time only a preliminary solution, not patching etc. `\section` etc.

The code redefines `\section` etc. slightly, using the old version and appends the definition of `\thesectionname` at the end.

However, using `\thesubsectionname` in the next section this would lead to wrong names, so I used the `\@elt` trick to kill recursively all `\the...names` at the start of a specific structure level.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{xparse}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\@kickthenames}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\@elt##1{\@ifundefined{the##1name}{}{\expandafter\gdef\csname the##1name\endcsname{---undefined---}}\@kickthenames{##1}}% Recursively kill the names
  \expandafter\csname cl@#1\endcsname%
  \endgroup
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\RedefineLevel}{om}{%
 \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\let\expandafter\expandafter\csname latex@@#2\endcsname\csname #2\endcsname%
 \expandafter\RenewDocumentCommand\csname #2\endcsname{som}{%
   \@kickthenames{#2}%
    \IfBooleanTF{##1}{%
      \expandafter\csname latex@@#2\endcsname*{##3}%
    }{%
      \IfValueTF{##2}{%
        \expandafter\csname latex@@#2\endcsname[##2]{##3}%
      }{%
        \expandafter\csname latex@@#2\endcsname{##3}%
      }%
    }%
    \expandafter\edef\csname the#2name\endcsname{##3}%
  }%
}

\makeatother

\RedefineLevel{section}
\RedefineLevel{subsection}
\RedefineLevel{subsubsection}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{A1}
\subsection[B1]{B1}
\subsubsection[C1]{C1}
\subsection[B2]{B2}
\subsubsection[C2]{C2}

The current section name is \thesectionname

The current subsection name is \thesubsectionname

The current subsubsection name is \thesubsubsectionname

\subsubsection[C3]{C3}

The current section name is \thesectionname

The current subsection name is \thesubsectionname

The current subsubsection name is \thesubsubsectionname


\section{Z}

The current section name is \thesectionname

The current subsection name is \thesubsectionname

The current subsubsection name is \thesubsubsectionname


\subsection{B1}

The current section name is \thesectionname

The current subsection name is \thesubsectionname

The current subsubsection name is \thesubsubsectionname

\subsection{B2}
The current section name is \thesectionname

The current subsection name is \thesubsectionname

The current subsubsection name is \thesubsubsectionname

\subsubsection{C1}

The current section name is \thesectionname

The current subsection name is \thesubsectionname

The current subsubsection name is \thesubsubsectionname



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent!  But I’m not sure that complete expansion of the section title, when saving it, is The Right Thing To Do: I’d go for `\protected@edef`, at least.

Comment: If you allow me to give another suggestion, wouldn’t `\def\@elt##1{\@ifundefined{the##1name}{}{\expandafter\global\expandafter\let \csname the##1name\endcsname \@undefined` be even better?  (The little pearl of using `\cl@...` is the part the delights me most… :-)

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti: Thank you. I will change as soon as possible

Comment: Thanks to you for this beautiful and enjoyable piece of LaTeX programming!